# How to query for objectid on mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to print all the object ids in a collection I have in mongoDB. I understand how to convert the `ObjectId` to a string, however I am not sure how to actually make a call to list all the object ids.

I tried the following from pymongo documentation but nothing happens because I have 4 `ObjectId`s

```
def get(post_id):
    Document=client.db.collection.find_one({'_id':ObjectId(post_id)})
    return Document
```

Comment: Hi joseph; can you explain what you mean when you say you have four ObjectIds, and how this makes the database query go wrong?

Comment: In my mongodb, I have a collection. Under that collection, there are four different objectIDs. I want to be able to return all 4 different object ids because afterwards i have a function that updates the database data but the data that needs to be updated depends on the object id. For example data X must be updated to object id X, data y to object id y, etc

Comment: Running the above code returns nothing. I want it to return the 4 unique object ids

Answer (score 2):

```
from bson import ObjectId

id = "5fec2c0b348df9f22156cc07"
objInstance = ObjectId(id)
  
collection.find_one({"_id": objInstance})
  
# below line works same as the above
collection.find_one({"_id": ObjectId(id)})
collection.find_one(ObjectId(id))
```

`bson` should already been installed once you installed `pymongo`